# C++ protected member inheritance

Tags: c++, access-control

My question is why I cannot call protected virtual member function in derived class through a pointer to the base class unless declaring derived class as a friend of base class?

For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
  friend class C;  // (1)
protected:
  virtual void foo() const = 0;
};

class B : public A {
  void foo() const override { std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl; }
};

class C : public A {
  friend void bar(const C &);
public:
  C(A *aa) : a(aa) { }
private:
  void foo() const override {
    a->foo();       // (2) Compile Error if we comment out (1)
    //this->foo();  // (3) Compile OK, but this is not virtual call, and will cause infinite recursion
    std::cout << "C::foo" << std::endl;
  }
  A *a;
};

void bar(const C &c) {
  c.foo();
}

int main() {
  B b;
  C c(&b);
  bar(c);

  return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
B::foo
C::foo
```

In the above code, I want to call virtual function `foo()` through member `a` of class `C` (not the static bound one through `this` at compile time), but if I don't make `C` as `A`'s friend, the call is illegal.

I think `C` is inherited from `A`, so that it can access the `protected` member of `A`, but why is it actually not happen?

Comment: Well, technically, `a->foo();` isn't a virtual call either. To call the method `foo` in your base class, call it like this: `A::foo ();`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius A call through pointer to base class isn't a virtual call? Besides, `A::foo` is a pure virtual function without definition, and I think a call like `a.A::foo` is bound at compile time and would be an error in this situation.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius No, as OP showed, the result of `a->foo()` is `B::foo`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Class `C` can access the protected members of its own base class, but not members of any other `A`.

In your example, the parameter `a` is part of the totally unrelated class `B` to which `C` has no access rights (unless you make it a friend).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still have a question: according to the standard, the access level of a virtual function is decided by its declaration in base class. So the compiler wouldn't know the parameter `a` is part of an object of class `B` at compile time. And how should I understand this question?

Comment: It actually doesn't matter if the `a` parameter happened to be part of some  other `C` object. The compiler cannot tell, if it just gets a pointer to an `A`. It has to have a known `C` object to be able to access its base class.